# end argument to print leads to different behavior with time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, time, printing

I tried to write this script that just prints number after each other on the same line with a one second delay, but it does not work.

Ex this works:

```
from time import sleep

for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n)
    sleep(1)
```

But this does not, the program just freezes:

```
from time import sleep

for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n, end="")
    sleep(1)
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: ops, I added the end="" now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program does not freeze, you just need to flush the stream by passing `flush=True`:

```
print(n, end="", flush=True)
```

`sys.stdout`, the stream that `print` uses by default, is line-buffered (when in interactive mode), as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr):

> - When interactive, standard streams are line-buffered

This means that when the *default* string used for `end` (`\n`) is encountered, a call to `flush` will be made. Using other strings (i.e `''`) don't trigger `flush`ing so you'll have to force it by using `flush=True`.